# Subject Verb agreement - Are vs. Is

Tags: grammar

I am tripped up with the correct usage of 'are' or 'is' in the following sentence. Any quick explanations as to why this simple sentence may cause confusion?

Here 'are/is' the list of scholarships and the application.

Comment: Quick answer: the sentence is not simple. What a native speaker would do is contract _Here_ into _Here's_ (one doesn't find _Here're_ -- nor _There're_, for the same reason -- as a contraction, because it's hard to pronounce, and contractions should make things **easier**). Once it's contracted, there's no need to worry about number agreement, and since the number that one might agree with goes from singular _list_ to plural _scholarships_ to conjoined plural _and_ to singular _application_ as the sentence ambles on, nobody's going to complain.

Answer (score 0):

When you use *and*, you're making a plural, compound subject.  That means *are* is the correct usage.

> Here are the list of scholarships and the application.

If it were just the list of scholarships, the subject is *list*, which is singular:

> Here is the list of scholarships.

If you want to use *is* for both, you have to divide it into two, so to speak:

> Here is the list of scholarships, and here is the application.